# Use one file for data connection in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project in php. where I have multiple files having data connection.And on the start of every file I write this code.

```
$servername = "localhost";

    $abcusername = "root";

    $abcpassword = "password";

    $dbName = "db";
```

When I have to change password , I edit every file and change password that is very hassle process for me.
Can someone help me that how to to store server information in one file and give the link in all other files.

Comment: Create new file `connection.php` and put this code inside that and `include('connection.php');` in every file

Comment: let me check first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create db.php file and place

```
    $servername = "localhost";

    $abcusername = "root";

    $abcpassword = "password";

    $dbName = "db";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $abcusername, $abcpassword, $dbName) or trigger_error("Unable to connect to the database");
```

and just use

```
include 'db.php';
```

in all of your files and use $con for posting your data to server eg:

```
mysqli_query($con,"your sql command");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a rudimentary environment file by simply having an array with various information.

Lets assume we have a file called `env.php`:

```
$connections = [
    'connection_1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'username' => 'some username',
        'password' => 'some password',
        'servername' => 'some servername',
        'db_name' => 'some db_name',
        'port' => 123456,
    ],
    'connection_2' => [
        // ....
    ],
    'connection_2' => [
        // ....
    ]
];
```

After which you can `require_once` the file in various places.

With that said I recommend you take a look on how different frameworks handle environmental variables([symfony example here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html)).

I don't expect you to implement the symfony example but it would give you a good idea on how to implement your own.